# Subsonic MySQL Version

Tags: .net, mysql, subsonic, mysql-connector

I understand that Subsonic 2.2 requires the MySQL.data  5.2.3 dll.  I'm trying to integrate a subsonic DAL for a VB project in Visual Studio.  The project already uses a lot of datasets.  Because of this, Visual Studio requires that I have the MySQL NET connector software installed, which automatically throws its own MySQL dll deep into my system.

The problem is that with the MySQl NET Connector installed on my system, I can't include the MySql.data 5.2.3 dll with my project because it complains that I have two conflicting versions of the same dll.

The closest Net Connector version I can find to install is 5.2.6.  Subsonic demands 5.2.3.  I can't seem to use both in the project.  What the heck am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build SubSonic from source using the MySql.dll that you are using in your project.  Thats what I did once.